# How to retrieve a value from my php array?

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

My query gives me a result in an array :

```
$donnnes =

Array ( [0] => Array ( [sku_code] => A1101_0090_TU [SKU_EAN] => 9346799868270 ) )
```

I put in comment what the var_dump of my variables give me, the variable SKU_EAN gives me a NULL value, how to recover the value of SKU_EAN (9346799868270) when it reads sku_code (A1101_0090_TU) in my csv file ?

```
 $resultat = mysqli_query($bdd, "SELECT trim(concat(concat(SKU_ITEM_VARIANT,'_'),trim(SKU_SIZE)))as sku_code , SKU_EAN  FROM dwh_dev.dwh_d_sku"); 

    $donnees[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultat); 
    print_r($donnees); //Array ( [0] => Array ( [sku_code] => A1101_0090_TU [SKU_EAN] => 9346799868270 ) ) 


    $constante = "MMXC1_";

    $temp2 = array_column($donnees, 'sku_code', 'SKU_EAN');
    var_dump($temp2); //array(1) { ["9346799868270"]=> string(13) "A1101_0090_TU"

            if (($handle = fopen("$nomcsv", "r")) !== FALSE) { 

                $firstLine = true;

                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000000, ";")) !== FALSE) 
                {   
                    if(!$firstLine) {

                        $sku_code = $data[6].'_'.$data[7].'_'.$data[8];
                        var_dump($sku_code); //A1101_0090_TU

                        $SKU_EAN = $temp2[$sku_code];
                        var_dump($SKU_EAN); //NULL

                        // Create line here and immediately add it to `$data_final`
                        $data_final[] = $constante.'|'.$SKU_EAN.'|'.$data[12].'|'.$data[13]; 
                     }
                     $firstLine = false;
                }   
            }


                     $cheminfile = "//alcyons/IT/PhotoShoot/retail/CSV/TXT_Finaux/MMX".date('His').".txt";

                    $fp = fopen("$cheminfile", "w");

                    $delimiter = ';';

                    fputcsv($fp, $data_final,  "\n");                              

                    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Because there is no such element in $temp2 ( $temp2[A1101_0090_TU])

Comment: How do I get it back?

Comment: To use `$temp2` as you are using you need a structure in `$temp2`  like this: `Array ( [A1101_0090_TU] => 9346799868270 )`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the parameters in the function array_column

Use this

```
$temp2 = array_column($donnees,  'SKU_EAN', 'sku_code');
var_dump($temp2); //array(1) { ["A1101_0090_TU"]=> string(13) "9346799868270"}
```

Instead of

```
$temp2 = array_column($donnees, 'sku_code', 'SKU_EAN');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it only inserts the first line in my txt file, is this normal? I wish he'd do that every time I run a loop in my csv.

Comment: Please check the data in array $data_final.

Comment: `var_dump($data_final) = array(1) { ["A1101_0090_TU"]=> string(13) "9346799868270" } array(1) { [0]=> string(26) "MMXC1_|A|9346799868270|0|0" } array(2) { [0]=> string(26) "MMXC1_|A|9346799868270|0|0" [1]=> string(13) "MMXC1_|A||0|0" } `

Comment: You need to loop $data_final array. Please see the modified answer.

Comment: I have a error : Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in...

Comment: Please ignore my edit. If your $data_final is a single dimension array, your code should work fine.

Comment: I think I have an error in retrieving the values of my query in $donnnes because in my .txt file it only fills the SKU_EAN of the first line and not the others...

Comment: Yes, You are getting only one record. See this link to get the data from Database. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: I have to use while ($donnees[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultat)) { }

Comment: Yes, you need to loop.

Comment: That's weird, I just added the loop at the beginning instead of $data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); but it doesn't add all the EANs in my CSV file...